# Let $X$ and $Y$ be 2 disjoint connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, can $X \cup Y =\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be 2 disjoint connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Then can $$X \cup Y =\mathbb{R}^{2}$$

I think this cannot be true, but I don't know of a formal proof. Any help would be nice.

Comment: it can be true. consider $X$ the set of all pairs in the non-negative orthant and $Y$ the set of all remaining pairs.

Comment: I think that you wanted to assume that the sets were open. In this case your statement is indeed not true (i.e. you are right), because $\mathbb R^2$ is a connected topological space.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Nope. My intuition was wrong.

Comment: @ronnie.in : $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected, so it is not the disjoint union of two _nonempty_ open sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean what you put, let $X=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:\ x\geq0\}$ and $Y=\Bbb R^2-X$ (so $X$ is the right half of the plane, including the $y$-axis, and $Y$ is the left half of the plane). Then clearly $\Bbb R^2=X\cup Y$ and $X\cap Y=\varnothing$.

If you mean for $X$ and $Y$ to be open, then the answer is negative, as then $\Bbb R^2$ would have a separation, that is, $\Bbb R^2$ wouldn't be connected, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

consider $X:=\{(x,0) :x>0\}$ and $Y:=\mathbb{R^2}-X$ ,Both are connected and disjoint but $X\cup Y=\mathbb{R^2}$